# ListView SelectedItems binding: why the list is always null

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, mvvm-light, uwp

I'm developing a UWP App, with Mvvm Light and Behaviours SDK. I defined a multi selectable ListView:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="MembersToInviteList"
    IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MemberTemplate}">

</ListView>
```

I'd like, with a button binded to a [MVVM-Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) [RelayCommand](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/e5294f54-f460-8227-b228-ac63034b1294.htm), to obtain a list with the selected items:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding AddMembersToEvent}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MembersToInviteList, Path=SelectedItems}"
    Content="Ok"/>
```

The RelayCommand (of MVVM-Light framework):

```
private RelayCommand<object> _addMembersToEvent;
public RelayCommand<object> AddMembersToEvent
{
    get
    {
        return _addMembersToEvent
            ?? (_addMembersToEvent = new RelayCommand<object>(
               (selectedMembers) =>
               {
                   // Test
                   // selectedMembers is always null!
               }));
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint inside the command, and I notice that selectedMembers is always `null`, although I select various items. By the console output I don't see any binding error or something else.

Also, if I pass as CommandParameter the whole list, and I put a breakpoint inside command's definition, i notice that I can't access to SelectedItems nor SelecteRanges value.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="MemberTemplate">

    <Viewbox MaxWidth="250">
        <Grid Width="250"
              Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"
              Background="{StaticResource MyLightGray}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource ShadowColor}"
              BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1"
              CornerRadius="4"
              Padding="5">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                  Width="45"
                  Height="45"
                  Margin="5,0,5,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  CornerRadius="50">

                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Center"
                                AlignmentY="Center"
                                ImageSource="{Binding Image.Url,
                                                      Converter={StaticResource NullGroupImagePlaceholderConverter}}"
                                Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                </Grid.Background>

            </Grid>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Margin="3"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundTextOverBodyColor}"
                       Style="{StaticResource LightText}"
                       Text="{Binding Alias}" />

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</DataTemplate>
```

What's the reason? How can I obtain such list?

Comment: Is the RelayCommand an `ICommand`-Implementation written by you or does it come from the MVVM-Light framework?

Comment: @Tomtom Mvvm MVVM-Light framework

Comment: Can you show us your ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the solutions to pass SelectedItems from ListView in ViewModel (with RelayCommands) is described in igralli's blog.

[Pass ListView SelectedItems to ViewModel in Universal apps](http://igrali.com/2015/03/05/pass-listview-selecteditems-to-viewmodel-in-universal-apps/)

Try the following code to get the selected objects from the parameter.

```
    private RelayCommand<IList<object>> _addMembersToEvent;
    public RelayCommand<IList<object>> AddMembersToEvent
    {
        get
        {
            return _addMembersToEvent
                   ?? (_addMembersToEvent = new RelayCommand<IList<object>>(
                       selectedMembers =>
                       {
                           List<object> membersList = selectedMembers.ToList();
                       }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to solve the issue. The code you posted isn't enough to make it work; also the link you posted sees the problem in another way: it binds the list of selected items every time you select an item, my problem were to bind it one time when a user clicks the button. Also I didn't used behaviours sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small example for your case without MVVM-Light and it works perfect.

Maybe the problem is within the RelayCommand-class. I've written the following:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<T> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute = null )
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (canExecute == null)
            return true;
        return canExecute((T) parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute((T) parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the other implementation of command, but it isn't working. Same issue. I just changed a tag to be more specific: UWP. (Before I couldn't put it due to max tags)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Roman's answer I figured out how to solve the issue:

First of all, as Roman suggested:

```
private RelayCommand<IList<object>> _addMembersToEvent;
public RelayCommand<IList<object>> AddMembersToEvent
{
    get
    {
        return _addMembersToEvent
               ?? (_addMembersToEvent = new RelayCommand<IList<object>>(
                   selectedMembers =>
                   {
                       List<object> membersList = selectedMembers.ToList();
                   }));
    }
}
```

Then, the XAML:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding AddMembersToEvent}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MembersToInviteList, Converter={StaticResource ListViewSelectedItemsConverter}}"
    Content="Ok"/>
```

The difference here is that I passed the whole list as parameter, not it's `SelectedItems` property. Then, using an `IValueConverter` I converted from the `ListView` object to `IList<object>` of `SelectedMember`:

```
public class ListViewSelectedItemsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var listView = value as ListView;
        return listView.SelectedItems;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this way the `RelayCommand<IList<object>>` got the right list and not a null value.

Comment: you may have found your solution but I ran your code given above without changing anything(with my relay command class) and it worked fine. selectedMembers always has values. I think the issue was with your RelayCommand Class.

Comment: In the solution above the RelayCommand is still MVVM-Light one (as in the question).

Comment: can you add this class in the question also? as I don't have MVVM-Light and also other who also go through this post might want that.

Comment: actually what I can't fathom in the solution is that if value was reaching NULL to RelayCommand, how is a converter able to provide it. I mean it's just another class and also doesn't do anything that would change anything in listview.

Comment: Could you paste the code of RelayCommand class in the question instead of web link as web link also doesn't have class def. I've to download the MVVM light and I can't install anything on my system. sorry for your troubles.

Comment: @Alok I'm sorry, but I think it isn't open source, so I can't access to ICommand implementation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101280/discussion-between-alok-and-francesco-b).

Comment: If you found the solution "Thanks to Roman's answer", why you mark your own answer as a solution? It's like liking your own photos on Facebook :)

Comment: Probably for the bounty? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a reason but you can easily skirt the issue altogether by having an "IsSelected" property on your Contact object and putting a check box on your template:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItemsOutput}"></TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="What is checked?" Command="{Binding GoCommand}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and VMs etc:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _selectedItemsOutput;

    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Contact> { new Contact() { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" }, new Contact() { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" } };

    public ICommand GoCommand => new RelayCommand(Go);

    public string SelectedItemsOutput
    {
        get { return _selectedItemsOutput; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedItemsOutput) return;
            _selectedItemsOutput = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void Go()
    {
        SelectedItemsOutput = string.Join(", ", Contacts.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.Name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isSelected) return;
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I can't put an "IsSelected" property to my contact model because I don't really have access to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Just my five cents and might be an absolutely long shot, but you should check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems.aspx):

> If the ItemsSource implements IItemsRangeInfo, the SelectedItems collection is not updated based on selection in the list. Use the SelectedRanges property instead.

I am just guessing based on Tomtom's answer, since he says he did almost exactly as you and got a working solution. Maybe the difference is in this little detail. I haven't checked it myself yet.